# LinearLayout замещается TextView

Tags: android, xml

Пытаюсь сделать простую шапку сайта + скроллинг. Я новичок в этом, так что получается фигня) Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему TextView размещается не под LinearLayout, а вытесняет его?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backqround_"
    tools:context=".HelpPage">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                android:text="@string/help"
                android:textColor="@color/red_"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="409dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="650dp"
                android:background="@color/light_purple"
                android:paddingRight="30dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/at_home"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/at_home"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="23sp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        tools:width="-20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/help5"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingTop="25sp"
                        android:text="@string/sign_out"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="23sp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                        android:layout_width="77dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@null"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Вот так получается]

Comment: Прочитайте документацию по RecyclerView и ConstraintLayout
это более подходит к вашей задаче

Comment: `LinearLayout` имеет атрибут `orientation` `Vertical`(колонки), `Horizontal`(Строки)
для пропорционального отношение елементов в `LinearLayout` есть атрибут `weightSum` и для елементов `layout_weight`